# How to switch current page in vaadin?

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin

I have java project generated on vaadin page. I'm using spring-boot and vaadin, There is any option to switch page visible on localhost:8080 from MainView class to another class?

I've tried to make it using removeAll(); and add(something) code, but I can't use it when I want to switch view on other class

I'm using vaadin 13

It's main class code:

```
@Route
```

@PWA(name = "Project Base for Vaadin Flow with Spring", shortName = "Project Base")
public class MainView extends HorizontalLayout {

```
public MainView(){
    VerticalLayout verticalMenuBarOnLeft = new VerticalLayout();
    VerticalLayout emptyLayout = new VerticalLayout();


    Button buttonGoToLogin = new Button("Idź do logowania");
    buttonGoToLogin.addClickListener(buttonClickEvent -> {
       removeAll();
       add(verticalMenuBarOnLeft, MainViewInterface.getSignInLabel(), emptyLayout);
    });

    Button buttonGoToRegister = new Button("Idź do rejestracji");
    buttonGoToRegister.addClickListener(buttonClickEvent -> {
        removeAll();
        add(verticalMenuBarOnLeft, MainViewInterface.getRegisterLabel(), emptyLayout);
    });

    verticalMenuBarOnLeft.add(buttonGoToLogin, buttonGoToRegister);


    add(verticalMenuBarOnLeft, MainViewInterface.getSignInLabel(), emptyLayout);
}
```

}

Comment: Which vaadin version? (Vaadin 7+8 use a swing approach, Vaadin 9+ use a router with views)  Please show your code.

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your other class with `@Route("")`

Explanation:
The `@Route` annotation is a shorthand for generating the view URL based on the class name. Normally this works so that the `-View` ending of a class name is dropped off, and then the rest is converted to kebab-case. So for instance `ExampleView` would get mapped to `/example`. The only exception is `MainView` which gets mapped to `/`.

Personally, I prefer to be more explicit and define the URL myself with `@Route("url")`